# PostgreSQL comparing one attribute in another relation to another?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Okay, cut a long story short Im working on a project where i need to find out if the capacity of a venue is less than 80% full. 
Ive got a table called Events and an event has a:

EventID
EventName
EventCrowd

In another table, ive got Venue as follows:
VenueID
VenueCapacity
VenueStyle

I need to use a JOIN to find out all the modules where the venue will be less than 80% full.

Im a bit stumped on how to do it!

Comment: you've given two tables with no relation...hard to join two tables that are not related.  Does your Event table have a 'venueID'?   Also...is event crowd the number of people currently at the venue (so 80% capacity can be expressed as where eventcrowd / venuecapacity >= .8?)

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: @IanMcannoly - Thats the information we need.  It's usually good stack etiquette to edit your question to include these details and not leaving them just in comments.  Aimers answer is pretty close to what I'd write, if it's not post a comment and we'll try again.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your post.

Comment: Just to make a note as a professional, I see nothing that could be directly related to your business or company in your post.  I see nothing 'sensitive' necessarily, because we don't have information about your employees or anything else.  I would argue instead that any *sensitive* information is nonexistent, because I've done questions like this before.

Comment: If you indeed believe that your question [contains sensitive information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132117/what-should-i-do-if-a-user-posts-sensitive-information-as-part-of-a-question-or), and you cannot delete it yourself, you can flag it for moderator attention by clicking the "flag" link below it and selecting the "in need of moderator intervention" option. Optionally, you may also edit out the sensitive parts of the question first, but I wouldn't recommend erasing the whole question; that just triggers anti-vandalism alerts and draws extra attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I got your question right, but here's an attempt with hardcoded values for demonstration:

```
SELECT EventsTable.EventID, EventTitle, EventCrowd, Time, Day, VenueCapacity, VenueStyle, EventCrowd/VenueCapacity::float AS PercentCrowd
FROM (
VALUES (1, 'FooFighters', 1000), (2, 'BarFighters', 1000)
) EventsTable(EventID, EventTitle, EventCrowd)
INNER JOIN (
VALUES (1, 1, 2, 'XX:XX', 'XX'), (2, 2, 1, 'YY:YY', 'YY')
) TimeTable(TimeID, EventID, VenueID, Time, Day)
ON EventsTable.EventID = TimeTable.EventID
INNER JOIN (
VALUES (1, 2000, 'Something'), (2, 1100, 'Something Else')
) VenueTable(VenueID, VenueCapacity, VenueStyle)
ON TimeTable.VenueID = VenueTable.VenueID
GROUP BY EventsTable.EventID, EventTitle, EventCrowd, Time, Day, VenueCapacity, VenueStyle
HAVING EventCrowd/VenueCapacity::float < 0.8
```

As result this will give you

```
EventID     EventTitle  EventCrowd  Time    Day VenueCapacity   VenueStyle  PercentCrowd
2           BarFighters 1000        YY:YY   YY  2000            Something   0,5
```